# Android Wear : Watch face with maps?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am a newbie with Android wear, though I have some experience with Android dev. I am planning to make a watch face with google maps in the background. Should I even try? Is it possible ?

I read the API documentation. Watch face is like a like a custom view, do everything in `onDraw()`. I plan to show map only in non-ambient mode.

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't be possible, but I doubt you'll want to use the mobile Maps API for it (far too heavyweight). If you only want it in the background of the face, a single image form the Static Maps API is probably a better bet: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/

Comment: @String Thanks for validating, I was thinking in same direction :)